# Collection array Manipulation through Page Templates Meteor?

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, collections, web-deployment

What I have at the Moment. I have a collection called Nodes.

```
Nodes = new Mongo.Collection('nodes');
```

I publish and subscribe correctly to this collection so that's not the problem
I insert some info for testing since these will be fore Weather stations.

```
if(Nodes.find().count() === 0) {
    Nodes.insert({
        name: "OSU Node 1",
        humidity: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    });
    Nodes.insert({
        name: "Storm Node 1",
        humidity: [11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,10]
    });
}
```

Now I have a sidebar that shows these nodes and loads a NodePage to display graph data of the node I selected.

```
<div class="nodes">
    {{#each nodes}}
        <li>
            <a href="{{pathFor 'NodePage'}}">
                {{name}}
            </a>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

**HTML** and then the **js** is just the generic

```
Template.sidebar.helpers({
nodes: function(){
    return Nodes.find();
}});
```

this works 
In my router it shows the _id of the node that was selected

```
Router.route('/:_id', {
   name: 'NodePage'
});
```

This page just currently has a link to `{{> graph}}` page. because there  is also one for gps. But here is the real issue. In the insert I have an array. I want to display just the array of the selected node. I have the _id on the page but cannot seem to get the singular node. I have gotten both nodes and their arrays.
I have the HTML of the `name="graph"` page

```
{{#each humid}}
    <ul>{{name}}
        {{#each humidity}}
            <a>{{this}}</a>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
{{/each}}
```

and the JS is just

```
Template.graph.helpers({
    humid : function(){
        return Nodes.find();
    }
});
```

this works but gives me both Nodes from collection and both arrays of each.

My goal is to be able to load a page. display a graph of that nodes Humidity data only. Not the other nodes in the collection. I have asked this question on many forums and many colleagues and no one can answer the question. 
Links to website and Github code. 
[My website for this code](https://echo-project-marcusjwhelan.c9users.io/) website link 
[Go to echo-project-work](https://github.com/marcusjwhelan/echo-project) Github link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some sample code to get the humidity array of a singular node, given that it comes in a parameter on Iron Router:

```
Template.graph.helpers({
  humid: function() {
    if( Router.current().params._id ) {
      let node = Nodes.findOne({ _id: Router.current().params._id });
      if( node ) {
        return node.humidity;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Hope that helps!  You should be able to modify your template to get what you want from there.

Comment: I am very new to Meteor, about 3 weeks. I think I made the Parameter on Iron Router right `Router.route('/:_id', {name: 'NodePage',
    data: function() { return Nodes.findOne(this.params._id); 
    }});` Although I am not quite sure about the HTML. I have only ever used the `{{#each}}` enclosure. I am looking up the other types.

Comment: I would upvote but I do not have enough points. But It worked. in the HTML I changed it to `{{humid}}
        <ul>{{node.name}}
        {{#each node.humidity}}
            <a>{{this}}</a>
        {{/each}}
        </ul>` and now it shows the numbers with a comma between. I don't need this for the final code but this is exactly what I need to accomplish right now. Later I will have to used this to cycle through and post this array into a grapher some how. Different problem. Although Thank you very much sir. Will the commas bother the data entry into a graphing equation?

Comment: Hmm that's really weird and I can't say for sure what's happening without more code.  It might affect how charting works, though, yes.

Comment: I figured out that the commas are just there because I am printing out the array itself so there are commas. So this will be fine on the code side because I will just be pulling in the first 100 points anyway.